# Element gone after page refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, web-storage

When someone enters the website I want them to not see some elements, but when user type in pass and username admin I want him to display `newprojection` element. It works but when I refresh the page it's gone. I tried web storage here but it still gone after page refresh.

```js
document.getElementById('newprojection').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('buyticket').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('newuser').style.display = "none";

function validate() {
  localStorage.setItem('test', boom);
  var boom = document.getElementById('newprojection').style.display = '';
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  if (username == 'admin' && password == 'admin') {
    localStorage.getItem(test);
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="branding">
      <h1><span id="logo">mov</span>BLANK</h1>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a id="newprojection" href="newprojection.html">New projection</a></li>
        <li><a id="buyticket" href="buyticket.html">Buy a ticket</a></li>
        <li><a id="newuser" href="newuser.html">New user</a></li>
        <li class="current"><a id="login" href="login.html">Log in</a></li>
        <li>
          <a id="nameofuser" href="#"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="container">
  <form>
    <p>Username</p>
    <input id="username" type="text" name="username" required>
    <p>Password</p>
    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" required>
    <a type="submit" id="login2" onclick="validate()">Login</a>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve here ... you want that, if the user types in 'admin'/'admin' they can  see the hidden element, even if they refresh the page? I mean, once you 'log in', you're logged in forever (or at least until localStorage is emptied)?

Comment: Yeah thats my point, i dont use and back end, this is only front end, and i wanted to do just like you said, if they type admin/admin they can see the hidden element and when i redirect the page to index.html, that they can still see that element but no this is going hidden again once i refresh or redirect to index.html, and the local storage should work but it doesnt, i mean its not saved on localstorage if it was it would show that hidden element even if i refresh the page.

Comment: `localStorage.getItem(test);` just retrieves the value.  You have to *do something* with the retrieved value.   (Also you're trying to set the value `boom` before you define it... as an empty string...)

Comment: As a side note, this sort of thing will not be secure at all, anyone who loads the page can look at the source and find out what the username/password are. It will stop people who are technically illiterate or lazy but anyone who wants to and has an ounce of technical skill will be able to see them.

Comment: yeah i know, i don't know php or node for now, but i will learn it, for now it's just a university project, thank you for advice :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can try this. It's not working as a snippet as invoking localStorage methods causes a SecurityException in my firefox.

```js
document.getElementById('newprojection').style.display = "none"; 
document.getElementById('buyticket').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('newuser').style.display = "none";

function validate(){
 var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
 var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
 if ( username == 'admin' && password == 'admin'){
    document.getElementById('newprojection').style.display = '';
  localStorage.setItem('isAdmin', 'true');
 }
}

window.onload = function() {
  var isAdmin = localStorage.getItem('isAdmin');
  if (isAdmin === 'true') {
    document.getElementById('newprojection').style.display = '';
  }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css">
 <title>movBLANK | Log in</title>
</head>
<body>

<header>
 <div class="container">
  <div id="branding">
   <h1><span id="logo">mov</span>BLANK</h1>
  </div>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a id="newprojection" href="newprojection.html">New projection</a></li>
    <li><a id="buyticket" href="buyticket.html">Buy a ticket</a></li>
    <li><a id="newuser" href="newuser.html">New user</a></li>
    <li class="current"><a id="login" href="login.html">Log in</a></li>
    <li><a id="nameofuser" href="#"></a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </div>
</header>

<div class="container">
 <form>
  <p>Username</p>
        <input id="username" type="text" name="username" required>
        <p>Password</p>
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" required>
        <a type="submit" id="login2" onclick="validate()">Login</a>
 </form>
</div>

<script src="../js/login.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you see, the `validate` function only shows the element when the user and password are 'admin'/'admin' and not before. If this is true, then se store and `isAdmin` property in localStorage. At page loading, we check for the existence of that property, and, if it does exist and is 'true', then we show again the hidden elements without the need to fill the form again.

Let me tell you, however, that this way of 'securising' an application is just wrong. Anyone can examine your code and know how to bypass your 'security'. And in any case, if they want to show the hidden items they can do it through the browser's developer tools.

Comment: Please sir, i copied your code and it  shows new projection, i don't want new projection to show, i want those 3 elements hidden, and when user types admin/admin that new projection shows AND when i refresh the page that new projection is still shown...i know this project is for school only so no worries xD...

Comment: I made a change. Try now

Comment: Sir, i copied again, and when i enter index.html the new projection is still being shown, i want home and log in to be shown only, and when i enter admin/admin in login form then i want new projection to be shown,and to stay shown even if i refresh the page.. if u don't help me am doomed, i googled the sh*t out of web storage but couldn't get it to work :(

Comment: I checked it and it works as expected: when first you open the page the three elements are hidden. Then, when you enter the credentials, new projection appears, and it keeps appearing forever when you refresh, are you are 'logged in'. As I warned you in my first comment, once you log in, you're logged in forever, even if you close the browser and open it again. Maybe you only want the user to be logged during the current session (until they close the browser)? In this case, you should use `sessionStorage` instead of `localStorage`.

Comment: Thank you sir, you are my savior, now i will examine your code letter from letter to understand it better, thank you for your feedback and help, it works as expected :D

Comment: can i contact you for one more quick question, it's similar to this just an add on, i won't bother you anymore after this :(

Comment: Yes, you may :-)

Comment: can you give me a contact email, to send you the code, or something else where i can send you the code...